# Spring Boot connection to MySQL remote database strato.de

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, host

[image]

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://rdbms.strato.de:3306/dbs1?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
    username: dbName
    password: my password
driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

I have to use the Database of strato Host , with the PHP it is possible but in IntelliJ IDEA 2022
my Spring Boot Project I have not any connection with the remote DB

get the Error

```
HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:111) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:98) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:90) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:74) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:895) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:820) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:446) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:239) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:188) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:359) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:470) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
```

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Make sure that your mysql server is active on `0.0.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.1` if your connection code is not within the same network as the database server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strato does not allow remote access to a database: [So nutzen Sie unsere MySQL-Datenbank](https://www.strato.de/faq/hosting/so-nutzen-sie-unsere-mysql-datenbank/#:%7E:text=Ein%20Zugriff%20per%20remote%20(also,)%2C%20ist%20somit%20nicht%20m%C3%B6glich.) (How to use our MySQL database)

> Aus Sicherheitsgründen können MySQL-Clients nur innerhalb des Netzwerks (SSH-Server, Webserver) auf die MySQL-Datenbank zugreifen. Ein Zugriff per remote (also vom eigenen PC bzw. von aussen aus), z.B. per ODBC (Open Database Connectivity), ist somit nicht möglich.

Translation:
*For security reasons, MySQL clients can only access the MySQL database within the network (SSH server, web server). Remote access (i.e. from your own PC or from outside), e.g. via ODBC (Open Database Connectivity), is therefore not possible.*

Comment: Danke für Ihre Mitteilung! aber ich hatte nicht verstanden, warum die Verbindung durch PHP möglich ist und in Spring Boot nicht!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you got your answer. But I did. They do not allow such connections.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you! that is right.